# Why is $OUTDIR$ duplicating part of the path

Tags: visual-studio

I am using the following line in my Post-build event command line in VS2017:

```
xcopy /d /y "$(ProjectDir)dll\*.dll" "$(OutDir)"
```

to move dlls to the `\bin\Debug` folder when building.  However the dlls in the `dll` directory end up in the folder `\bin\Debug\bin\Debug`.  `$(OutDir)` is set to `\bin\Debug`.  I have not touched or changed that from the default project generated.  What reason would cause the path to be duplicated like that?

For this dll, I am unable to add it as a reference because it VS does not seem to support it (gives an unsupported/invalid error when I browse and add it).   The dll does interface well in C# despite that.

Comment: What reason is there to copy the Dlls when that is done by Visual Studio itself? References are copied already. If you have some native dlls that you want to include, add them to the project and set their post-build action to `Copy Always` or `Copy Newer`.

Comment: Also, did you check what do you have in the Output Path textbox under your project properties (Build Tab)?

Comment: I am not able to add the dll as a reference because it is not considered valid in that way (give unsupported/invalid error).   However, it runs fine if it's included in the build directory with `[DllImport]` in C#.   Output Path is set to `\bin\Debug`

Comment: Then just follow the second advice from @PanagiotisKanavos about native dlls